# unable to install component/event while making a 'component'

Tags: javascript, uicomponents, component.io

I was following along with this: http://tjholowaychuk.tumblr.com/post/37832588021/building-a-date-picker-component

However, when I do, `component install component/event`, it doesn't download the required component or add it to dependencies.

Why is it so and how can I get it working?

Comment: with component 1.0.0 `component install component/event` should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

`$ component create`

and then this

`$ component install component/event`

my result looks like this: my component.json get a new entry

`"dependencies": {
    "component/event": "*"
  },`

and there was created a **components** directory

`$ tree components/
components/
└── component-event
    ├── component.json
    └── index.js`

`$ component -V
0.19.7`